# how can I deploy wp_pagenavi in "News Custom Post Type" plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed "News Custom Post Type" plugin for news in wordpress. Its working fine but want to integrate with another plugin for pagination wp_pagenavi.

I am very new to wordpress and php. can anybody know here as to how can I switch wp_pagenavi with news plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Edit Post` page, can you please add:

```
<?php
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query= null;
  $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'Post-Type_Name',
                                 'paged' => $paged,
                                 'post_per_page' => 10)
                           );
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

More information, please look at:

Comment: I am not seeing edit post page. In news plugin there are just add news, categories and tags

Comment: @LifeSaver Is it possible to share the WP-Admin details to my email? You can find it in my profile page.

Comment: @LifeSaver I haven't got any emails. Did you check my profile for the email address? See at the end of `Brief Intro`. `:)`

Comment: have you received it now

Comment: are you there in chat

Comment: @LifeSaver Nopes. Why?

Comment: to correct pagination. As you can see there are 12 news but it displays 1 page

Comment: @LifeSaver `#social-media-icons {position: absolute; right: 0;}`

Comment: Thanks. please check it again its on bottom of top bar. can I move it little bit high from bottom?

Comment: `#social-media-icons {position: absolute; right: 0; top: -15px;}`

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: When I resize the browser to check how this will work for mobile or other devices then these media icons are not adjusting automatically. What should I do for that?

Comment: @LifeSaver You may hide it in smaller browsers, or use `position: static; float: none;` for smaller resolution.s

Comment: We already set its `position: abolute;` when I write `position: static; float: none;` then its not accepting css anymore

Comment: `#social-media-icons { 
  width: 270px;
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0;
  top: -15px;
  !position: static; 
  float: none;
}
#social-media-icons li{
  width: 50px; 
  display: inline-block;
  height: -110px;
}`

Comment: What's this? `!position` invalid one!

Comment: when I remove ! sign then all icons going here there because we already set its position

Comment: Here is my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186708/how-can-i-modify-specific-attribute-in-css. Please answer it to mark your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97536/discussion-between-lifesaver-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: Hello, I added wordpress default button from its visual editor as: <p style="text-align: center;">[symple_button url="http://websitename.com/index.php/clinical-consultation-2/" color="green" size="large" border_radius="3px" target="self" rel="" icon_left="" icon_right=""]Read More[/symple_button]</p>. I am not able to change its color to #00A500
any advise please. @Praveen please help

Comment: What exactly is `[symple_button url=`?

Comment: This is html: <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://asc100.com/index.php/our-products" class="symple-button large green   " target="_self" title="Visit Site" style="border-radius:3px" rel=""><span class="symple-button-inner" style="border-radius:3px">Read More</span></a>

Comment: @LifeSaver You have an unnecessary `;` in there.

Comment: This is auto generated by wordpress. Can you please let me know how can I change color green to any other color