# How can I modify specific attribute in CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress. The following piece of code resides in loo-services.php

```
            if($ct_options['ct_book_now'] == 'Yes') {
                echo '<p>';
                    echo '<a class="book-now btn" href="#" data-service="';
                        the_title();
                    echo '">' . __('Book Now', 'contempo') . '</a>';
                echo '</p>';
            }
```

This piece of code generates through `data-service="the_title()"` method.

There is a button on the website "Book Now" When this button clicked then its forwarding to the default page.

I want when "Book Now" button clicked then forward user to another page rather then its default page that is used from `data-service="the_title()"`.

On homepage there is a link of default service e.g. "Clinical Consultation". When this is clicked then link auto directs to its default page whereas I want to link this to custom page that I build in page builder e.g. This link www.website.com/index.php/clinical-consultation-2 instead of its default page link?

Comment: what does "link" have to do with css?  css tells your browser how to format/display a page. it has nothing to do whatsoever with what a link points at, or where the link takes you when you click it.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB. It means I have to set in php file but how?

Comment: This php code is linking page that I build in services section whereas I want to link customized <a href> tag for each page

Comment: I am seeing data-service="" with page titles. Is this a good to add if statement that if data-service==this then <a href=this> ...... something like this?

Comment: @LifeSaver That seems like a good idea...

Comment: I don't know abc of php. if I write in this way like if(data-service="'example title'"){ <a href="http://myexamplewebsite.com">} Please correct the syntax

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Please don't ask the OP to explain the problem over Skype. If a more thorough explanation is needed, then the OP should edit their question where we *all* can understand it better.

Comment: @j08691 I just thought of helping the OP in a better way, sorry if that's wrong. `:(`

Comment: Quentin, showdev, easwee, greg-449, @HaveNoDisplayName I tried to explain my question again. Please un-hold it so that I can get answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a redirection plugin: [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) and that would serve the need:

1. Download redirection.zip
2. Unzip
3. Upload redirection directory to your `/wp-content/plugins` directory
4. Go to the plugin management page and enable the plugin
5. Configure the options from the `Manage/Redirection` page

Answer (score 0):

With the incomplete information you provide in your question I would try something like this:

```
        if($ct_options['ct_book_now'] == 'Yes') {
            echo '<p>';
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
            echo '</p>';
        }
```

Comment: what is difference between code in my question and your code?